# Execute SSIS Package in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssis

Are there some way to execute a SSIS Package that I have in a document library in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess, I'll delete if it's inaccurate, since SharePoint exposes the "Open with Explorer" option, it seems that one can operate on SP libraries like they're *normal* file system objects. Given that assumption, you should be able to run a package via the command line like

```
dtexec /file "http://server/sites/subsite/db/Shared Documents/Package.dtsx"
```

I don't have any packages in our Site or I'd test that. dtexec threw a package not found exception instead of flinching at the `http` portion so that's seems promising.

Comment: try
                                {
                                    strCmdText = "dtexec /file http://XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXX.dtsx";
                                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
                                }
But nothing happends....

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on the MSDN forums and it seems like it should be possible as long as the account running the package (SQL Agent or your account) has the right permissions to SharePoint.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/916fb8e9-63a2-43e3-8195-c09ccfeb020d